# How to connect iOS app to a hardware over wifi? Is it possible

Tags: ios

I have this situation and I hope that anybody will be able to help me with.
So we have some hardware devices that needs to be controlled by an iOS app (either all together or one at a time which ever possible to be implemented) and in return the hardware returns values to the app! Possible scenarios:

1. The iPad acts like a hotspot and the devices connects to it then the app control the hardware and read data from it. In this way no need for a router.
2. The hardwares connects to a local network where the iPad also connected then the app controls the hardware and can read data from (I think this can be done as if was a printer and an app communicate with the printer over wifi).

Now, I have no information how to do that or if this is even possible. I searched online but couldn’t find that much of info about it.

I appreciate all the help on this.

Thanks

Comment: Tell the user to go into settings and change networks to the AP

Comment: Do you want to use wifi-direct to configure the hardware from your app? If the hardware is just an access point, you need to tell the user to select in settings. The wifi accessory configuration feature is [covered by the mfi program](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action)

Comment: My understanding is they need the app to communicate with the hardware to get data from and send data to it. You can think about it as a medical device that send analytics or reading to the mobile app, and at some point the app might control the hardware as well!

Comment: update: We are using Bonjour services where the hardware connects to a router and the listen to bonjour services and then open a outputStream and inputStream connection. This is the solution.